# Configure custom winston logging transport in sails

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, winston

How can I configure winston in sails to use a mongodb transport?

This seems to be on the right track, but with a different transport.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sailsjs/67u7SqzsNJQ

Here is my present config, modeled on that:

http://pastebin.com/SNJxBNak

Sails automatically runs any functions that a config file exports, right?

The function notify() doesn't seem to be running.

I am new to sails and hating it.

Comment: if you figured this out, please share! I'm stuck on something similar!

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue and I tried extending this one [Sailsjs - Custom Logging with Winston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258774/sailsjs-custom-logging-with-winston)

**After extending above link, the working solution:**

Create a new js file inside a config folder(code inside of this will be executed automatically by sails) and add mongodb transports as below,

```
var winston = require('winston');
var MongoDB = require('winston-mongodb').MongoDB;

var customLogger = new(winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new(winston.transports.MongoDB)({
            db: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test',
            collection: 'logs',
            level: 'debug'
        })
    ]
});

module.exports.logging = {
    colors: false, // To get clean logs without prefixes or color codings
    custom: customLogger
};
```

And use it anywhere like

```
sails.config.logging.custom.debug("winston mongodb transport logging");
```